# "extending" enum

Tags: java, enums

I have multiple enum's that all have the same constructor and attributes, like this:

```
enum Enum1 {
    A(1,2),
    B(3,4);

    public int a, b;
    private Enum1(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}


enum Enum2 {
    C(6,7),
    D(8,9);

    public int a, b;
    private Enum1(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

and so on...
Unfortunately Enum1 and Enum2 already extend Enum, so it isn't possible to write a superclass they could extend.
Is there another way to archive this?

**Update:** here comes a "real-world" example. Think of a classic rpg, where you have items, armour, weapons etc. which give you a bonus.

```
enum Weapon {
    SWORD(3,0,2),
    AXE_OF_HEALTH(3,4,1);

    // bonus for those weapons
    public int strength, health, defense;
    private Weapon(int strength, int health, int defense) {
        this.strength = strength;
        this.health = health;
        this.defense = defense;
    }
}

enum Armour {
    SHIELD(3,1,6),
    BOOTS(0,4,1);

    // bonus
    public int strength, health, defense;
    private Weapon(int strength, int health, int defense) {
        this.strength = strength;
        this.health = health;
        this.defense = defense;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have separate `Enum` classes for enums which have pretty much the same data? Why can't `C` or `D` go in `Enum1`? I think giving us the concrete scenario might help in reaching closer to the real solution.

Comment: See [Java extend enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414755/java-extend-enum).

Comment: Sorry to say it but this design doesn't look right. Of course YMMV but those attributes are better off on "individual" shields, boots etc. I'd recommend having "items" which have a type field, which in turn would be an enum *without* attributes. Of course there are other ways of doing it but please make the information available as part of class attributes (driven from configuration) rather than making them "hard-coded".

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma So you would do this: [see pastebin](http://pastebin.com/QdipY9n3). Then how could I get e.g. a random SUFFIX?

Comment: @user28061: No, still doesn't look right. Why are you so fixated on using an "enum"? Why can't those entities be a different class on it's own (e.g. `GameEntity` as opposed to an `enum`? Tying yourself up with an enum for stuff (game entities) which usually is pretty dynamic, has behaviour and is part of a logical hierarchy (i.e. might need inheritance features) is a big mistake IMO. Start with regular classes and code up stuff which addresses the immediate concern (working game) rather than fighting with enum limitations. :)

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma I came across this issue several times, it is not limited to this rpg example. What I like about enums is that the are fast/easy to compare.

Comment: @user28061: Unfortunately that doesn't justify their usage pretty much everywhere IMO. "Fast and easy" comparisons are a side-effect of enums (since each enum instance is a singleton) but not the reason for using enums. YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums extend Enum. They cannot also extend something else. However, they can implement interfaces.

You can make them both implement a common interface, and put your getA(), getB() methods on the interface.

Answer (score 3):

You have to combine them (or not if thats not a good idea)

```
enum Enum1 {
    A(1,2),
    B(3,4),
    C(6,7),
    D(8,9);
```

Comment: Sorry, but those enums still have to be seperate.

Comment: In that case, you have to have an Enum1 as you have now and one combined Enum2.  Why can't you have one combined enum type?

Answer (score 1):

```
No, you can't extend enums in Java.
```

As Peter mentioned you can combine them.

My be [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/enums_and_mixins) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this and than add flag to your enum:

```
    public class ExtendetFlags : Attribute
    {
        #region Properties

        /// 
        /// Holds the flagvalue for a value in an enum.
        /// 
        public string FlagValue { get; protected set; }

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        /// 
        /// Constructor used to init a FlagValue Attribute
        /// 
        /// 
        public ExtendetFlags(string value)
        {
            this.FlagValue = value;
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public static class ExtendetFlagsGet
    {
        /// 
        /// Will get the string value for a given enums value, this will
        /// only work if you assign the FlagValue attribute to
        /// the items in your enum.
        /// 
        /// 
        /// 
        public static string GetFlagValue(this Enum value)
        {
            // Get the type
            Type type = value.GetType();

            // Get fieldinfo for this type
            FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());

            // Get the stringvalue attributes
            ExtendetFlags[] attribs = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
                typeof(ExtendetFlags), false) as ExtendetFlags[];

            // Return the first if there was a match.
            return attribs.Length > 0 ? attribs[0].FlagValue : null;
        }
    }
```

Using is simple:

```
`            [ExtendetFlags("test1")]
            Application = 1,
            [ExtendetFlags("test2")]
            Service = 2
`
```