# How can I return more than one value from a method in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following method:

```
    public static ?? GetType6()
    {
        var name = "x";
        var age = 1;
        return ??
    }
```

Called like this:

```
    var ?? = GetType6();
```

I would like to be able to call that method and get back the name and age. I thought of creating an anonymous object but 
then if I do that how can I decode it?

Comment: One can always use Containers or to Make a Class and return a pointer to one of its instances.

Comment: I wish, you should have studied few basics before jumping to code. Though not sure of your programming background, but as per my knowledge, any application programming language provide Classes/structures to encapsulate the fields and exchange data apart from a lot other things like methods/events etc. to modify the behavior/state of the object(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be to return a [`Tuple<string, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) (available since .NET 4):

```
public static Tuple<string, int> GetType6()
{
    var name = "x";
    var age = 1;
    return Tuple.Create(name, age);
}
```

You can read the values in this way:

```
var pair = GetType6();
string name = pair.Item1;
int age = pair.Item2;
```

Of course more robust, readable and maintainable is to create a class:

```
class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age{ get; set; }
}

public static User GetUser()
{
    var name = "x";
    var age = 1;
    return new User{Name = name, Age = age };
}

var user  = GetUser();
string name = user.Name;
int age = user.Age;
```

Comment: Tim, do you use tuples in production in C#? I've tried it, but always found, that creating a custom class makes code much more readable. You access elements via `Item1` and `Item2`, which is very obscure. I found tuples great in languages like F#, where you can use pattern matching, but is it worth it in C#?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov I almost never expose tuples from public or internal methods; I find it much more readable to write a simple immutable wrapper class with properly named properties.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: I use them only for internal code. So for example in one class in private methods. I would never use it for code that is used by classes that are not related. Sometimes you don't want to create a class for everything because that class could be redundant or misleading. So in this case a `Tuple` might be not the best choice since OP wants a `public static` method.

Comment: @MatthewWatson and Tim, this is where probably you will disagree with me, but I don't even see the point of using tuples for internal parts. If a type is used inside a method's scope - anonymous type is a good solution. If it is used outside method, even inside assembly or even some low-level module, I don't see the good point in Tuples. I always try to remember the proverb - write code as if it will be maintained by a maniac, who knows where  you live". And he definitely will want to ask me why I use `tuple.Item1` as a actual parameter for a name argument, for example.

Comment: @Tim - thanks very much. I will accept this answer. I have another question related to this. How to return a list of tuples. I will write that question now.

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you just create a type to hold whatever you want?

```
public static MyType GetType6()
{
   MyType type = new MyType();
   type.name = "x";
   type.age = 1;
   return type;
}

class MyType
{
   public string name {get;set;}
   public int age {get;set;}

   public MyType()
   {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tuple :

```
public Tuple<int, int> GetMultipleValue()
{
    return new Tuple<int,int>(1,2);
}
```

You can have more details here :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

Answer (score 0):

using `out` keyword , it is possible as below:

```
public static string GetType6(out int age)
{
   var name = "x";
   var age = 1;
   return name
}
```

- The `out` keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference.
- This is similar to the ref keyword, except that `ref` requires that the variable be initialized before being passed.
- To use an out parameter, both the method definition and the calling method must explicitly use the out keyword.

Note : It is **bad** practice to use this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366741/what-is-bad-practice-when-using-out-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Use `dynamic` as return type:

```
public static dynamic GetType6()
{
    var name = "x";
    var age = 1;
    return new { name = "x", age = 1 };
}
```

Method call:

```
var v =  GetType6();
```

SO question: [Variable Return Type of a Method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499791/variable-return-type-of-a-method-in-c-sharp)
MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use anonymous types as you said. Like this.

```
public static object GetType6()
{
    return new { name = "x", age = 1 };
}
```

To read the values you have to use reflection.

```
var foo = GetType6();
var name = foo.GetType().GetProperty("name").GetValue(foo, null);
var age = foo.GetType().GetProperty("age").GetValue(foo, null);
```

Though it's a very dirty way of accomplishing what you need.