# How can I populate and return a list of tuples in C#

Tags: c#

I had a good suggestion on how to retun a tuple from a method:

[How can I return more than one value from a method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230661/how-can-i-return-more-than-one-value-from-a-method-in-c-sharp)

Now I realize that my code produces not just two values but an IEnumerable< >.  Here's my code so far where result contains an IEnumerable of I guess an anonymous object containing notes and title. I am not quite sure how to put the data into the tuple and not sure how to get it out of the variable myList. Can I do a foreach over myList ?

```
    public static IEnumerable< Tuple<string, string> > GetType6()
    {
        var result =
            from entry in feed.Descendants(a + "entry")
            let notes = properties.Element(d + "Notes")
            let title = properties.Element(d + "Title")

        // Here I am not sure how to get the information into the Tuple 
        //  
    }

    var myList = GetType6();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the [`constructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267681.aspx):

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> GetType6()
{
    return
        from entry in feed.Descendants(a + "entry")
        let notes = properties.Element(d + "Notes")
        let title = properties.Element(d + "Title")
        select new Tuple<string, string>(notes.Value, title.Value);
}
```

But honestly what would cost you to make your code more readable and work with models:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public static IEnumerable<Item> GetType6()
{
    return 
        from entry in feed.Descendants(a + "entry")
        let notes = properties.Element(d + "Notes")
        let title = properties.Element(d + "Title")
        select new Item
        {
            Notes = notes.Value, 
            Title = title.Value,
        };
}
```

Manipulating tuples IMHO makes the code very unreadable. When you start writing those `result.Item1`, `result.Item2`, ..., `result.Item156` things become horrible. It would be far more clear if you had `result.Title`, `result.Notes`, ..., wouldn't it?

Comment: `return =` Is this a valid syntax?

Comment: I prefer the [`Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387181.aspx) methods. `select Tuple.Create(notes.Value, title.Value);`

Comment: @Darin - I do agree with you about using models but this is just going to be used in one single place for a data load and then once the data is loaded I will be removing the source of the data and not using it again. thanks for your help as always I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Gemma, what difference does it make if it will be used in one single place in the code? Is this a reason to make this place unreadable? I am just saying that from my experience people making such *compromises* in one place usually end up with many *many compromises* and a net result of completely unreadable code. You should never sacrifice the readability of your source code.

Comment: If it's only being used in one place, maybe make `Item` a private, nested class.